# Is it possible to erase or override zsh's prexec() error behavior?

Tags: git, zsh

I recently found out about preexec() and precmd() functions in zsh, and came up with a novel way to use squeeze a little more functionality out of my shell.

This prexec() function checks to see if the 'command' you have just attempted to run
begins with 'http' and ends with '.git', if it does, it automatically will cd to my source directory and check the source out. So I just paste it in and hit enter and it's off to the races. Otherwise, any normal (or errors) should look normal.

```
function preexec() {
  [[ "$1" =~ "^http.*.git\$" ]] && cd /usr/local/src && git clone "$1"
}
```

The thing that's got me stymied right now is that there doesn't appear to be any way to ignore or overwrite the 'command could not be found' error that you get.

> zsh: no such file or directory: https://github.com/someproject.git

I tried overwriting '1', ZLE_LINE_ABORTED, flipping around 2>&1, returning 1, 0, using noglob.. etc etc. no luck.

Any zsh smarties know how to suppress the error message?

Comment: It looks as if, at the time preexec() is executed, the shell has already tried to find the command to execute, so the behaviour you see kind of makes sense. You might have more luck implementing this as a completion function in zsh's command line editor. That makes the interface slightly different, of course, but maybe that's not a bad thing. It might even be possible as a zle-line-finish widget, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I hadn't considered making it a completion based task. I guess if I paste it and hit tab thats the same number of strokes as pasting and hitting enter. :p

Comment: You probably want to use `command_not_found_handler` instead of `preexec` since you are looking to run something *instead* of the URL, as opposed to something *before* the URL.

Comment: Hm. I tried something as simple as `command_not_found_handler () { print $1; return 0; }`, which does not seem to be called if the missing command is a URL. `zsh` seems to be trying to access the URL before deciding that it is a missing command name.

Comment: @chepner I tried this, too, in a slightly modified version (at the end of this comment) and it worked, zsh 5.0.2. Maybe something else is intercepting the URL in your setup? I don't see anything in zsh's docs that suggests URLs are tried as commands in any way by default. `command_not_found_handler() { [[ "$1" =~ "^(https|git|(git\\+)?ssh)://.*\\.git\$" ]] || return 1; echo $1; return 0 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is not to use the pre* functions and instead use the command_not_found_handler function. This should also work in newer versions of bash as well.

Credit goes to @chepner and @"Jan Krüger" for both of their efforts on getting this question resolved.

```
function command_not_found_handle {
        if [[ "$1" =~ "^(https|http|git|(git\\+)?ssh)://.*\$" ]]; then
                echo "Do something: $1"
                return 1
        else
                return 0
        fi
}
```

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63099402/1772898 is related to your question. Can you please check?