# git url as a command

Tags: bash, zsh

When I enter a git repo url in terminal it says:

```
% https://github.com/chmln/sd.git        
zsh: no such file or directory: https://github.com/chmln/sd.git
```

I want `https://github.com/chmln/sd.git` to act as a command which will

```
git clone https://github.com/chmln/sd.git
cd sd
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: I removed both `.bashrc` & `.zshrc` but the `no such file or directory:` error message is there when I use `https://github.com/chmln/sd.git` as the command in both bash and zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP provides more detail on use case. Worth addressing this use case specifically. When a command (git clone in this case) should be assumed, consider ERR trap with the BASH_COMMAND (or $_)

```
trap 'try_gc' ERR
function try_gc {
    local x=$BASH_COMMAND
    if [[ "$x" = https://* ]] ; then git clone "$x"; fi;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use an `ERR` hook rather than `command_not_found_handle`?

Comment: @chepner please check the [edit history of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63099402/1). That has the details regarding `command_not_found_handle`

Comment: If it's relevant information, it shouldn't be hidden in the edit history. Nothing about the question as it stands precludes its use. (Looking at the edit history, the problem is in the use of `/usr/lib/command-not-found` to implement the hook, not the hook itself.)

Comment: @chepner can you please share the solution is the answer section. That way we will be able to appreciate it.

Comment: To complement the excellent comment given by chepner (I did not know about this hook before either): It is described in the _zshmisc_ man page in the section named **COMMAND EXECUTION**.

Comment: My other answer covered why command-not-found does not work here. Basically, because it does not apply when the command contain ‘/‘. I removed other pot as per request from OP.

Answer (score 0):

OP here, the zsh specific solution that is working for me is

```
function _accept-line-with-url {

    if  [[ $BUFFER =~ ^https.*git ]]
    then

        echo $BUFFER >> $HISTFILE
        fc -R

        BUFFERz="git clone $BUFFER && cd $(basename $BUFFER .git)"
        zle .kill-whole-line
        BUFFER=$BUFFERz
        zle .accept-line
        # zle reset-prompt  
    else 
        zle .accept-line
    fi 
}

zle -N accept-line _accept-line-with-url
```

There is an easier solution. However, it does not `cd`:

```
alias -s git="git clone"
```